# Image from an array HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

This is a basic question but most examples I find are a little bit too complex.

I am trying to create an array of photos, and then display only a selected one.

This is my array:

```
var imgArray = new Array();
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'images/pie1a.png';
imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'images/pie1b.png';
imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'images/pie2a.png';
imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'images/pie2b.png';
```

This is my HTML:

```
<img src=imgArray[1] width="33" height="32">
```

I also tried this:

```
document.write('<img src="' + imgArray[1] + '" width="120" height="120"/>');
```

The photo is never displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not pasted you HTML...

Comment: Shouldn't `<img src=imgArray[1] width="33" height="32">` be `<img src=imgArray[1].src width="33" height="32">` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var imgArray = [
    'images/pie1a.png',
    'imgaes/pie1b.png',
    // ...
];
document.write('<img src="'+imgArray[1]+'" width="120" height="120" />');
```

Note that `document.write` is not a good idea, it should be avoided, but if it at least gets your code working it's a good start!

Comment: I agree.  You're better off giving the original image an ID and use:  document.getElementById("name").src = imgArray[1]

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'images/pie2b.png';
```

you need to write:

```
document.write('<img src="' + imgArray[3].src + '"/>'); 
// please note the '.src'
```